# Laravel 8.0: Saving "Not Null" String attribute in a Model as an Empty String

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I created a new model named "WalletAddress", that have the following migration file:

```
Schema::create('wallet_addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->comment('User Owner of address');
            $table->string('alias')->comment('alias name for the address');
            $table->string('type')->comment('Address type');
            $table->string('address')->comment('Wallet Address');
            $table->enum('status',[
                'Confirmed',
                'Pending',
                'Deleted',
            ]);
            $table->json('address_properties')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

The Model class is defined as the following:

```
class WalletAddress extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = [
        'address_properties->confirmation_Validity_deadline',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'address_properties' => 'json',
    ];

    public function addressOwner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I tried to create and save a new instance of the model, using the following code:

```
$walletAddress = new WalletAddress([
    'status' => 'Pending'
    ]);
$walletAddress->save();
```

I got the result in the DB as a new record saved with all "Not Null" VARCHAR Fields like 'alias, type, address' saved as an empty string, and the bigint field like user_id saved as 0.

I am using upgraded Laravel 8.x with MySQL 8.0 Database

Why Laravel didn't prevent saving the attributes with `Not Null` restriction, if it is not exists in the creation of the model object?
Is that related to PHP casting of `Null`?

Comment: I found the problem .. it seams that the project was updated from Laravel 5.6, which sets the parameter `strict` in `config/database.php` file to `false` .. this will allow saving the `null` values to the equivalent type in MySQL:
convert null into empty string in case of VARCHAR
convert null to 0 in case of bigint
and so on ..
By changing the `strict` value to `true` in in `config\database.php` file .. it will prevent saving the null values ..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem .. it seams that the project was updated from Laravel 5.6, which sets the parameter `strict` in `config/database.php` file to `false` .. this will allow saving the null values to the equivalent type in MySQL:

- Convert null into empty string in case of VARCHAR
- Convert null to 0 in case of bigint and so on
  By changing the `strict` value to `true` in in `config\database.php` file .. it will prevent saving the null values .. and it is the default value for Laravel >= 5.7